# Using inequalities on cost of two items.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> A pen and a pencil cost an integer number of cents. It is known that 175 pencils cost more than 125 pens but less than 126 pens. Prove that
>   3 pencils and a pen cost more than $1.

Let a pencil cost p cents and a pen cost q cents.
$$126q>175p>125q$$
$$126q\geq 175p+1 \\
175p\geq125q+1$$
Then,
$$126q\geq 125q+2$$
$$q\geq2$$
So 
$$175p\leq 126q-1\\
175p \geq 125q+1$$
Combined with the last inequality
$$251\leq 175p\leq 251$$
$$p=\frac{251}{175}$$
But that means 
$$3p+q\geq \frac{1103}{175} <<< 100$$
How can I get stonger bounds on q, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: You made a mistake just after “combined with the last inequality”.

Comment: @Mindlack 
Could elaborate more on my mistake? Thanks

Comment: This is not an algebraic number theory question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, $$125q<175p<126q\\\frac{125}{175}<\frac pq<\frac{126}{175}$$
Also, both $p$ and $q$ are positive integers, so the problem has been reduced to finding the rational number $\frac pq$ with smallest denominator such that $\frac pq\in\left(\frac {125}{175},\frac{126}{175}\right)$.

Personally, I found this with a quick computer program.  But checking  [Minimal $ab$ for Rational Number $a/b$ in an Interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278763/minimal-ab-for-rational-number-a-b-in-an-interval), the accepted answer contains a solid algorithm for calculating the solution essentially based on the continued fractions of the two endpoints.  In either case, $(p,q)=(23,32)$ is the minimal solution.

Even in this smallest case, $$3p+q=3(23)+32=101$$ so the total cost must be larger than one dollar.

Comment: How would you find them mathemtically>

Comment: @Baker013273213 Good question.  I just expanded my answer to tackle that.